# Make device network requests always timeout

Tags: android, timeout, connection-timeout

In my app I have lots of network requests, pulling/posting data to/from our server. I'm wanting to check what happens with these when the device has no connection and when it times out to make sure I have appropriate warnings/alerts etc. No connection I can easily test, but I can't make the requests timeout.

Does anyone know any tricks for how to do this? I'm thinking some sort of proxy setup/invalid setup might work, but I know very little about proxies.

Comment: Do you use HttpClient for your I/O?

Comment: I use https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http this library, which it says is built on top of Apaches HttpClient

Comment: Hmm, you can lower the timeout from 10 seconds to 1 second but this will probably not make it time out. See http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.html

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you can use the emulator to try different type of connection, from the [doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking). You can set it up by command line or from the GUI

[image: In your app target]

Or better, from [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html)

[image: Look at "Emulator Control"]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the emulator, my work pc wont run it. Tried leaving it for over an hour and it never got past the Android splash loading screen.

Comment: I was afraid of something like that. Unfortunately I never tried to delay the network on a real phone, so I will let other answer your question.